# Django "No Such Table" Error - Django-seo2

Tags: python, django

I've very recently started to get into Django, so I apologize if this is a noob question.

I'm attempting to add the package "Django-SEO2" to a project of mine, but I keep getting this error:

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: djangoseo_mymetadatamodelinstance

I've been following this package's tutorial here: http://django-seo2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction/tutorial.html#introduction-tutorial

I created an seo.py file within my Post app with the exact code from their tutorial, and I successfully added it to the admin screen based on their instructions. That seemed to work fine, and the models populated in the admin screen as expected, but when I go to click on the item in the admin screen, I get the above error.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: I did make the migrations before adding it to the admin, and that seemed to have worked as expected.

Comment: you must run `python manage.py migrate` to create the required database tables

Comment: Right, sorry should have mentioned that I did the migrations before adding to the admin screen, and those seemed to have worked properly. I'll edit my question to say that I've already tried this.

Comment: what is your Django version ? This project is not tested with Django 1.10 (which is the current stable release). see https://github.com/romansalin/django-seo2 (supported Django (1.7, 1.8, 1.9))

Comment: Ah, that could very well be causing the problem..I'm using 1.10, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
python manage.py makemigrations appnamet
```

or:

`./manage.py schemamigration research --auto` to find that fields that
 didn't have a default specified.

`./manage.py schemamigration research --init` followed by `./manage.py migrate research`